# How can I copy a single worksheet from one .XLS file to another?

Tags: c#, excel

I'm struggling to copy an entire worksheet from an existing .XLS file into a new Excel file I'm creating within my application. This is my code so far:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook tempworkbook = workbooks.Open(
           Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Template.xlsx", //FileName
           0, //UpdateLinks
           true, //ReadOnly
           5, //Format
           Type.Missing, //Password
           Type.Missing, //WriteResPassword
           true,//IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended
           Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, //Origin
           "\t", //Delimiter
           false, //Editable
           false, //Notify
           0, //Converter
           false, //AddToMRU
           1, //Local
           0 //CorruptLoad
           );
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet tmp1 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)tempworkbook.Sheets["GSM Data"];
        string test = tmp1.get_Range("B2", "B2").Value2.ToString(); //test to see if sheet can be accessed - value should be "Database";
        tmp1.Copy(Type.Missing, wsGSMData); //copy worksheet into wsGSMData (which is the sheet in the new XLS file)
```

However the error I'm getting on the last line is:

> The server threw an exception. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT))

Essentially, the sheet I've extracted as `tmp1` should go into the sheet called `wsGSMData`, which is a sheet (one of 7 sheets in total) that i've created within the new .XLS workbook (called subsetworkbook):

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet wsGSMData = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)subsetworkbook.Sheets["Sheet7"];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: where did you get wsGSMData? Is it running in the same Excel process (i.e. did you obtain it through the same Excel application object)?

Comment: That's one of 7 sheets I created within the new XLS workbook (subsetworkbook) that i've created: subsetworkbook.Sheets.Add(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 7, Type.Missing);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet wsGSMData = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)subsetworkbook.Sheets["Sheet7"];

Answer (score 0):

Probably you've got an issue with Access Mode for your Excel file, which causes **(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT))**.

Try to check settings in Excel menu: *Review > Share Workbook > Allow changes by more than one user...* - you should try to deselect this check box.

Then go back to your code and check any lines, where you could possibly change this settings, especially *SaveAs* function. If you see *xlShared*, replace it with *xlExclusive* (see example below).

I've had the same problem while trying to add charts to file. No googled solution can help in my case, so I've got to figure out, what's going wrong, by myself. After trying to add charts into a fresh new file by different methods, I realise that aforementioned exception in this line:

```
Microsoft::Office::Interop::Excel::ChartObject ^ExcelChartObj = ExcelChartObjs->Add(100, 100, 300, 250); //create chart object (left, top, width, height)
```

was actually caused by the fact, that original file had *"Allow changes by more than one user"* checkbox selected from the start, and moreover, my own code also re-saved it as *xlShared* - twice! (Nope, double saving is not an error, it is how it should be in my case, cause my program solves a huge task, and I need to input data into the same file in two different steps during it)

Here's the working code (for C++/CLI Windows Forms), which finally made *(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT))* to disappear in my case:

```
ExcelApp->ActiveWorkbook->SaveAs(ExcFileName, Microsoft::Office::Interop::Excel::XlFileFormat::xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Type::Missing, Type::Missing,
    Type::Missing, Type::Missing, Microsoft::Office::Interop::Excel::XlSaveAsAccessMode::xlExclusive, Type::Missing, Type::Missing, Type::Missing,
    Type::Missing, Type::Missing); //save Excel book (access mode - xlExclusive, not xlShared!)
```

I hope it will help someone out there too! :)